# Strange exception on jbooss 5.1 javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Tags: exception, jboss5.x

In one of our client deployments of jboss5.1 mysql and an JSF application we get this one line error

```
16:46:08,970 ERROR [org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy] [] - [] (WorkManager(2)-17)  javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
```

it happens every 15 seconds eaven if we dont have any chron jobs on that time scale.

We have two ears deployed on the server and if I undeploy one of them the error stops. So it must be something related to the aplication. The strange thing is that we have not touched that ear for a long time and this error started to appear withowt redeploy or any code change.

Any hints on how can I dig furthure to resolve this strange error?

Comment: Do you get any exception stack trace along with this?

Comment: no thee given line is the onliy line about this in the log so no aditional stack trace

Answer (score 0):

go look at the following link

https://community.jboss.org/message/830295

https://community.jboss.org/message/635405?_sscc=t